# How to hide use of filtering on a given port? (nmap -sS targethost shows "filtered")

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

I have a software listening on port 1234 that I would like to keep hidden from outside world. I know that I can say e.g.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT ! -s 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

to make the port 1234 accessible only for the remote host 1.2.3.4.

However, other hosts can still run `nmap -sS myhost`, `nmap -sW myhost` or some other advanced test to see output such as

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
1234/tcp filtered someservice-guessed-from-port-number
```

For basic `nmap` scan (as normal user instead of root) the port 1234 appears to be closed.

Note that this output is identical regardless if any software is actually running on port 1234 or not.

**Is it possible to use `iptables` to make the port 1234 appear totally identical to normal closed port for all hosts except the selected ones?** I know that I could modify all ports to appear as filtered but that seems like a workaround instead of true solution.

Comment: Note that `nmap` uses the `-sS` by default if you run it as `root`. If you run it as normal user, it will run `-sT` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reply with RST:

```
-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```